# How to create a facebook publish button to post the scores?

Tags: javascript, browser, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have created a game that runs in the browser. After the game is over, I want the score to be posted on Facebook. Can anyone help me out with this, by giving sample code?

Comment: http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/5-steps-to-publish-on-a-facebook-wall-using-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create simple html button with `onclick` event wich creates [`FB.ui` dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/).

Comment: Thanks Anpher. That worked. But when I changed 123050457758183(app id in the example) to my app id I am getting an error which says (on the login screen) "Invalid Argument. Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration." I am not able to figure out what this means.

Comment: Sounds like application is not configured correctly. Go to your facebook apps then edit app. Check "Site URL" and "Site Domain" fields under "Web" tab.